# How to plot specific points in array with matplotlib?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib

I generated two arrays with 10 different values. How do I plot 3 specific values within each array using matplotlib? Here is my code so far:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as plt
x = np.array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
y = np.array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
```

I only want to plot the points 3,4,5 of the x-array and it's corresponding y values. I have tried this:

```
plt.plot(x[2,3,4], y[2,3,4])
plt.show()
```

But I get the error "too many indices for array." However, if I write

```
plt.plot(x[2], y[2])
plt.show()
```

the second element in the arrays will plot.

Comment: Try: `x = np.array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)` --> `x = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])` the same for y. And in plot: `x[2:5], y[2:5]`

Comment: I think you also want to import the `pyplot` submodule: `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! How do I do this if I wanted to only plot 3 different random elements in each array? For my actual data, the elements are not are in order from least to greatest

Comment: Then instead of plotting x[2,3,4], you can type x[np.array([2,3,4])] ! If x is a numpy array you can select elements with a another numpy array :)

Answer (score 4):

The problem is the syntax of `x[3, 4, 5]`. It is wrong what you want to do is `x[3]`, `x[4]`, `x[5]`, which are the respective elements of the array.

```
print(x[3], x[4], x[5]) # print 4, 5, 6
```

A more comfortable way to do this is:

```
plt.plot(x[2:5], y[2:5])
plt.show()
```

Where `x[2:5]` returns from the third to the fifth element.

As [Tony Tannous](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6530695/tony-tannous) says, the creation of the array is also wrong. `np.array` needs a list!

Then you also have to change the creation of x and y:

```
x = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
y = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
```

Adding `[` and `]` to make it a list.

Surely you should see the documentation of [Indexing](https://docs.scipy.org./doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html)

Comment: You still have to wrap the array elements by `[]` in np.array. https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html